# How do I format text to wrap onto a second line using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to format the image below to have the text wrap onto a second line if it doesn't fit on the first line.  If it has more text than would fit on a second line, it truncates.   I also have multiple images that I'm doing for consecutively.  I'm unclear on how to do this and I'm using Bootstrap for my CSS.  Any advice on how to do this?

## edit: updated image with overflow: hidden removed.

I am trying to get the second line to align with the first line after image of the person.
[image]

## html in template, using django

```
    {% for video in feed %}     
        <!-- wrapper div -->
        <div class='wrapper'>           
            <!-- image -->
            <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
            
            <div class = "image_container">
                <div class = 'imageblur'>   
                    <a href="{{video.3}}"> <img src = "{{video.2}}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <p style = "width: 290px; font-size: 12px; word-wrap: break-word;"><img src = "http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.username}}/picture">
            {{ video.1|truncatechars:80}}</p>
            
            </div>
            <!-- end image div -->
        </div>
        <!-- end wrapper div -->
    {% endfor %}
```

## css

```
div.wrapper{
    float:left; /* important */
    position:relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */ 
    padding: 5px;
}

div.imageblur{
    position: relative; 
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 250px; 
    filter: blur(5px);
       -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
       -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
       -ms-filter: blur(5px);

   margin:-1px;
   padding:1px;
}

div.image_container{
   width:248px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It will wrap if you remove the `overflow: hidden;` Dont know django though, and no clue what the bootstrap in django does.

Comment: @DamienOvereem I removed overflow: hidden and it still doesn't work. To clarify, I'm not trying to hide text. I'm trying to get it to wrap onto a second line if necessary that is aligned with the first line.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: I've never done anything like that myself, but it looks like what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `word-wrap: break-word;` this is what worked for me

Comment: There won't be any word wrap happening if you have overflow: hidden;

Comment: Then just remove `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I removed overflow: hidden and it still doesn't work. To clarify, I'm not trying to hide text. I'm trying to get it to wrap onto a second line if necessary that is aligned with the first line. The "..." in the image above currently is due to django's truncatechars:40 tag.

Comment: Did you also add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the text container?

Comment: I updated the code with word wrap and overflow:hidden; I've included a screen grab of what I see now.  I'm trying to get the second line to align with the first line (after the image of the person).

Comment: now put `overflow: hidden;` on the `<p>` tag that you want to wrap

Comment: then remove `overflow: hidden` from `div.image_container` and add `float: left` to `div.image_container`